# RediSearch PHP expects me to define all the fields on every use

Tags: php, redis, redisearch

Creating a new Index and adding data in same step is working as [seen in the docs](https://www.ethanhann.com/redisearch-php/).

But when i try to add data to an existing index I'm getting the following exception.

Ehann\RediSearch\Exception\FieldNotInSchemaException

```
The field is not a property in the index
```

Here is my code:

```php
$adapter = new PredisAdapter();

$host = config('database.redis.default.host');
$port = config('database.redis.default.port');
$database = config('database.redis.default.database');
$password = config('database.redis.default.password');
$redis = $adapter->connect($host, $port, $database, $password);

$bookIndex = new Index($redis, 'books');

$bookIndex->add([
    new TextField('title', 'Tale of Two Cities'),
    new TextField('author', 'Charles Dickens'),
    new NumericField('price', 9.99),
    new NumericField('stock', 231),
]);
```

I've looked into the source code of `redisearch-php` and it seems that there is no way this could work without always adding the fields with `addTextField` or others. But this seem not very practical to me. I thought I had to add the fields once on index creation. Am I wrong?

The `getFields` method (used in some methods like `makeDocument`) gets the object vars from `Index` but the field related object vars aren't in the instance if not added manually beforehand.

vendor/ethanhann/redisearch-php/src/Index.php

```php
/**
 * @return array
 */
protected function getFields(): array
{
    $fields = [];
    foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $field) {
        if ($field instanceof FieldInterface) {
            $fields[$field->getName()] = clone $field;
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param float $weight
 * @param bool $sortable
 * @param bool $noindex
 * @return IndexInterface
 */
public function addTextField(string $name, float $weight = 1.0, bool $sortable = false, bool $noindex = false): IndexInterface
{
    $this->$name = (new TextField($name))->setSortable($sortable)->setNoindex($noindex)->setWeight($weight);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param bool $sortable
 * @param bool $noindex
 * @return IndexInterface
 */
public function addNumericField(string $name, bool $sortable = false, bool $noindex = false): IndexInterface
{
    $this->$name = (new NumericField($name))->setSortable($sortable)->setNoindex($noindex);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 * @return IndexInterface
 */
public function addGeoField(string $name, bool $noindex = false): IndexInterface
{
    $this->$name = (new GeoField($name))->setNoindex($noindex);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding documents by using the associative array method? it's in the docs. if that doesn't work I'll try set this up myself and see what I can find out.

Comment: Yes, i tried all the documented ways including the assoc array. All of them resulted in the same exception. hence i looked into the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I played around with this today. I think you are correct. You have to redeclare the schema each time even if it already exists on redis. I can't see any functions that are used to pull the schema from redis which is kind of annyoying.

You can see the fields in the output from the $bookIndex->info() function but it doesn't set up the schema for you.

My solution to this problem would be to create a class that deals with setting up the index object so you don't have to keep doing it all the time. Something like this:

```
class book_index
{
    private $index;

    public function __construct($redis)
    {
        $this->index = new Index($redis);
        $this->index->setIndexName("book");
        $this->set_schema();
    }

    private function set_schema(){
        $this->index->addTextField('title')
            ->addTextField('author')
            ->addNumericField('price')
            ->addNumericField('stock');

        // attempt to create the index, I couldn't find any function to check if it already exists
        // so catching the failure or using info() and catching the exception on that was the only way
        try {
            $this->index->create();
        }catch (Ehann\RediSearch\Exceptions\RediSearchException $exception){
            error_log("book index already exists.");
            error_log( $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function get_index(){
        return $this->index;
    }

    public static function get($redis){
        $obj = new self($redis);
        return  $obj->get_index();
    }
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
include_once ("book_index.php"); // include the class file 
$adapter = new PredisAdapter();

$host = config('database.redis.default.host');
$port = config('database.redis.default.port');
$database = config('database.redis.default.database');
$password = config('database.redis.default.password');
$redis = $adapter->connect($host, $port, $database, $password);

$bookIndex = book_index::get($redis);

$bookIndex->add([
    new TextField('title', 'Tale of Two Cities'),
    new TextField('author', 'Charles Dickens'),
    new NumericField('price', 9.99),
    new NumericField('stock', 231),
]);
```

You could move more functionality to the class but I just tried to keep it simple.

Comment: what a bummer. would not have thought that.